# ASP.NET Session State in Cluster

Tags: asp.net, session-state

Our project was implemented originally with in memory session state. We need to scale up and add another server in an IIS server farm. I did all the steps to get the session state stored in a sql server database, but not all my objects are serializable, and db session state does require serializable objects.

My current thought is to create another layer of structs to mirror all the data that need to be serializable, and store them in session. When I need access to my object, I would use an adapter to morph the session struct into the object I need. Is this the way to go, or are there better options (other than manually making sure my current classes are serializable)?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work to avoid serializing objects.  If you really don't want to do that, you could use a state server instead of SQL Server for session management.

Comment: I looked into this as well, the objects need to be serializable as well for a session state server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Load Balancer of the farm should be configured to serve all requests of a client to the same server.

Comment: Not understand why downvote? A comment please. This solution has some limitations like fail-over (see Persistence paragraph from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)). Maybe in this case this should not be a problem: a server down all associated users should relogin, also in a single server deployment you have same issue. The requirements were to scaling up, no mention of fail-over.

Comment: Not sure who did down vote, but, you are focusing on a different aspect. Fail over or hot-swapping makes requests go to one server, and if that fails, it swaps in the secondary server. This provides only redundancy and can serve the same amount of users as  if you used one server (if things don't crash). Having multiple servers with a load balancer allows for serving a lot more users than a single server.

Comment: No, it is for scaling. Check also http://daveonsoftware.blogspot.com/2007/08/load-balancer-persistence-sticky.html